# Need help storing a zoomed in picture on Nikon D3200

Tags: nikon

I have many pictures that I have taken on the RAW setting for editing purposes on my Nikon D3200 camera. I am able to zoom in on a subject in the picture but cannot figure out how to save that zoomed in picture. For instance, in quick edit mode I can zoom in on a bird in the picture bringing it into closer view but cannot save that zoomed in picture.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean in the camera's built-in RAW conversion interface, or PC software?

Comment: I am guessing you are using NikonView NX? Just google "NikonView NX crop" and "NikonView NX export" and tutorials in text and video from can be found easily.

Comment: Quick edit mode sounds like Photoshop Elements?

Comment: Although not from the sounds of the title...

Comment: What software are you using to edit? How do you "zoom in"?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are using the D3200 in-camera editing features:

The *Quick Retouch* option will only allow you to edit and save the amount of auto saturation and contrast. It allows you to zoom to get a better view of a particular part of the picture, but you cannot save a crop from that option.

You need to use the *Trim* option that is near the top of the list just below D-Lighting and Red-Eye Correction.

- Use the +/- button to zoom in or out
- Rotate the command dial to cycle through different aspect ratios
- Use the four arrow keys on the multi selector to move the area of the crop around on the picture
- Use the *OK* button in the middle of the multi selector to save the crop as a new JPEG

It is all on page 152 of your Reference Manual.

With NEF (RAW) files, I would recommend you first use the *NEF (RAW) processing* option outlined on page 157 and then apply the crop to the new JPEG saved from that operation using the *Trim* menu option.

Comment: Doesn't that cause double-save in JPEG format, lowering the quality?

Comment: There's no other way to apply both in-camera. If you crop first all that you can edit with any of the other options is the JPEG you saved when you cropped the NEF. You can't even do RAW processing in that case. A simple trim of a JPEG without also resizing shouldn't affect the quality of the image that much, since no pixels are being re-dithered. If you Trim a full resolution 6016X4000 NEF to 3008X2000, the saved JPEG will also be 3008X2000. You are basically just discarding the other 1/2 of the pixels and rewriting the header.

Comment: If quality is the primary issue, the editing should be done elsewhere with a true RAW converter that allows more than one menu option to be applied to the NEF file before it is convereted to JPEG.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple to do in camera:

- Select picture.
- Press OK, this brings up the retouch menu.
- Press OK to trim.
- Adjust size with +/- buttons and maneuver into position using the multi selector button (around the OK button).
- Then press OK again.
- You're done

Alternatively - pages 330/331 D3200 for Dummies.

Comment: Welcome to [photography.se]. This answer doesn't really add anything to the answer that's been on the site for 7 years already.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess you're not doing this in-camera, but in Photoshop Elements.  If so, in Quick Edit mode, don't zoom in, just select the Crop Tool from the tools menu (shortcut is the "C" key on your keyboard).  You'll get a frame you can position around the area you want to save.